# Convert 3d matrix to String and back to 3d matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am currently working on a stenography assignment on how to embed secret image to a cover image using Wang's algorithm. Basically i just want to change for eg:
**3d matrix**

```
A(:,:,1) = [5 7 8; 0 1 9; 4 3 6];
A(:,:,2) = [1 0 4; 3 5 6; 9 8 7];
A(:,:,3) = [7 9 3; 4 5 9; 1 9 9];

To

Str = '578019436104356987793459199'
```

and also vice-versa if anybody can help out.

Comment: I assume A will always have integers

Comment: Typing `doc num2str`, `doc str2double` and `doc reshape` should be a good starting point

Comment: Vice versa will be possible only if all elements of your matrix are within 0-9 integers

Comment: Does it matter if you reshape row-wise or column-wise?

Comment: @gnovice Would definitely be easier - especially if the transforms are invertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to just use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).  You first need to transpose each slice independently, so the call to `permute` as per Ander's answer will get to that point.  After you can just supply a single format string of `%d` (integer) and the actual permuted matrix and it will unroll all elements column-wise and concatenate all of the numbers together.  The additional advantage is that you no longer need to assume that only one digit occupies each matrix element:

```
str = sprintf('%d', permute(A, [2 1 3]));
```

## Example

```
>> str = sprintf('%d', permute(A, [2 1 3]))

str =

578019436104356987793459199

>> class(str)

ans =

char
```

However, to reconstruct the matrix, you will have to assume that there's one element per matrix.  In this case, you could use the undocumented `sprintfc` function that can output one cell per character, then convert the characters to numbers with `str2double`.  Finally, reshape your matrix and undo the transpose:

```
A2 = permute(reshape(str2double(sprintfc('%c', str)), size(A)), [2 1 3]);
```

## Example

```
>> A2 = permute(reshape(str2double(sprintfc('%c', str)), size(A)), [2 1 3])

A2(:,:,1) =

     5     7     8
     0     1     9
     4     3     6


A2(:,:,2) =

     1     0     4
     3     5     6
     9     8     7


A2(:,:,3) =

     7     9     3
     4     5     9
     1     9     9
```

Comment: @AnderBiguri lol. It was a fluke. I was doing something similar a couple of days ago.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant,thanks a lot. It worked perfect. But if i may ask,what is the use of the last matrix ( [2 1 3] )? If you can just give me an idea.

Comment: @NigussuSima No problem at all. The `[2 1 3]` is for the `permute` function.  It rearranges the dimensions to the desired order. This means that the first dimension of the **output** matrix is the second dimension of the **input** matrix, the second dimension of the output is the first dimension of the input and finally the last dimensions stay the same.  By swapping the first and second dimensions, you are effectively transposing each 2D slice independently. We do this because MATLAB is column major and so when doing `sprintf`, it unrolls the columns so you are effectively processing per row.

Comment: @rayryeng amazing.....so lets say am reading a 512 X 512 image and i want to  arrange the rgbs of the 3d matrix the same way you arranged 3X3X3 sample matrix using permute function, how is the arrangement of the last block supposed to be? I'm sorry for asking again but this is the last time.

Comment: @NigussuSima I'm sorry I don't quite understand your question.  What does a 512 x 512 image have to do with a 3 x 3 x 3 matrix?

Comment: for eg:
i = imread( %some image of size 512X512 );
the entities of the rgb are saved as
i(: , : , 1) , i(: , : , 2), i(: , : , 3)  for row and column size both 512pixel
my aim is  to get this values into a single string,do modifications on them to embed a secret image using Wang's algorithm and finally return it to the 3d rgb matrix to display the final image on the screen.

Comment: If it is your desire to grow the original matrix from a 3 x 3 x 3 to a 512 x 512 x 3, then the method is the same.  It will give you a string of size `512 * 512 * 3` but please be aware that reconstruction would not be possible because for image pixels, their dynamic range usually extends beyond single digits.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the order of the unrolling of MATLAB matrices, your problem is slightly less straightforward than it may seem. You need to use `reshape` and `permute` to make it work.

```
str=arrayfun(@num2str,reshape(permute(A,[2 1 3]),[],1,1)).';
A2=permute(reshape(arrayfun(@str2double,str),[size(A)]),[2 1 3]);
isequal(A2,A)
```

This of course assumes what @Sardar comments in your question: all numbers have single digits (i.e. are integers range 0-9)

Comment: Possibly faster: `str=char(reshape(permute(A,[2 1 3]),[],1,1)+'0')`, `A2=permute(reshape(str-'0',size(A)),[2 1 3])`

Comment: @LuisMendo uhh. Want to add it in a separate answer?

Comment: Nah, it's the same idea. Just a minor comment to avoid `arrayfun` (but then the code becomes a little less readable)

Comment: @LuisMendo It may be faster to use `sprintf`. See my answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Good idea!